# Grid of elements with no margin around the outside

Tags: html, css

Seems like a simple thing, but I can't seem to find the right search keywords to help me out. I'm half expecting this to be a duplicate.

How do I make a grid of html elements that have margins on the inside, but not on the outside, like so (blue are normal elements with content, black are the margins):

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

I've found a hacked up method of doing the sides using

```
:nth-child(4n-3){margin-left:0}
:nth-child(4n){margin-right:0}
```

but there has to be a better way of doing this. I thought `display:table-cell` might help me but it doesnt seem to help. This is not for tabular data.

Here is my original rough source code but am quite open to using any structure:

```
<style>
.foo
{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #b4c6e7;
    margin: 10px;
}
.foo+.foo
{
    clear: none;
}
.bar
{
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div><div class="foo">content</div>
    <div style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are they in 3 separate row containers?

Comment: kindly post your code as well

Comment: Please excuse me, my english is not very well, and when I read the question seems to me like @Nacht looking for INSIDE BORDERS, just that. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first-child and last-child to override the borders, like the following very quick code.

I have used a table as you say this data should be displayed in a grid. The same effect can be used for similar effect, but tables start off shaped in a grid so are easy to demo.

Background colors are added so you can easily see which styles are applying to which cells.

```css
.datagrid {
    border-spacing:0px;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:purple;
}

.datagrid td{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
}

.datagrid tr td:first-child {
    background-color:red;
    border-left:0px;
}

.datagrid tr td:last-child {
    background-color:green;
    border-right:0px;
}

.datagrid tr:first-child td {
    border-top:0px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.datagrid tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:0px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="datagrid" >
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/jec2gcg2/ for the working example.

Comment: ah! yes, i see, the `<tr>`s cover the entire top, and each `<td>` will be a new first child... may use something like this, we'll see. i could probably use the same principle with `<div>`s

Comment: Yes you can defiantly use the same principle with div's, just have div's with different classes to represent table, row and cell.