# Remove outside margins in a grid of buttons

Tags: css

I have a group of buttons I am flowing in a grid-like display. As the width of the page changes the buttons to flow and rearrange themselves to fit.

The question [Grid of elements with no margin around the outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449153/grid-of-elements-with-no-margin-around-the-outside) shows how I would like my buttons and the spacing look, but I'm not using a `<grid>`.

I do know that since the buttons are fixed width, there will usually be left and right padding in the `<div>`. However, at a certain page width, the `<div>` should be able to touch the sides of the buttons.

It would seem to me the perfect (and easiest) solution would be to have `<div style="padding:-7px;">`, because that could 'absorb' the outside margin. However, a negative padding does not seem to be allowed.

```css
    .qlink {
      border: none;
      background-color: #1F70C4;
      color: white;
      margin: 7px;
      height: 35px;
      width: 150px;
      font-size: 12px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .qlink:hover {background: #2484E9;}
    .qlink:active {background: #155292;}
```

```html
  <div style="text-align: center; border-style:solid; padding:0px;">
    <a href="https://google.com/1">
      <button class="qlink">Awards</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/2">
      <button class="qlink">Directory</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/3">
      <button class="qlink">Patent</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/4">
      <button class="qlink">Calendar</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/5">
      <button class="qlink">Leave Request Tool</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/6">
      <button class="qlink">Publications</button>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Currently it looks like

[image: Grid with outside margins]

But I would like it to look like

[image: Grid with no outside margins]

(As an aside, this is how it renders in BBEdit's Preview. Anyone know why the 'dashes' show up in the horizontal rows? I don't think they are actually dashes. I think they are spaces with an underline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, use css grid

```css
.grid {
  text-align: center; 
  border-style:solid; 
  padding:0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 7px;
}
.grid a button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #1F70C4;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.qlink:hover {background: #2484E9;}
.qlink:active {background: #155292;}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <a href="https://google.com/1">
      <button class="qlink">Awards</button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://google.com/2">
      <button class="qlink">Directory</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/3">
      <button class="qlink">Patent</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/4">
      <button class="qlink">Calendar</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/5">
      <button class="qlink">Leave Request Tool</button>
    </a>

    <a href="https://google.com/6">
      <button class="qlink">Publications</button>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: PS. You don't need a button inside anchor element. It can be styled in the same way as button.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use your solution and simplify without the button element as well.

Answer (score 1):

The dashes are caused by the browser default styles of the `a` tag. Please see my flex-box based solution below.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 7px;
  padding: -7px
}

.qlink {
  background-color: #1F70C4;
  color: white;
  // margin: 0 7px 7px 0;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a.qlink:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.qlink:hover {
  background: #2484E9;
}

.qlink:active {
  background: #155292;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="https://google.com/1" class="qlink">
      Awards
    </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/2" class="qlink">
      Directory
    </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/3" class="qlink">
      Patent
    </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/4" class="qlink">
      Calendar
    </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/5" class="qlink">
      Leave Request Tool
    </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/6" class="qlink">
      Publications
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! I like the option of having the buttons fill the space. However, fela's answer below answers my question most directly and leaves the button size as is.